Не отображается форма Django на HTML странице
Вроде бы все сделал правильно, не вижу проблемы, может вы подскажите?
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Item
from .forms import CommentForm


def product_detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=product_id)
    comments = product.comments.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.user = request.user
            new_comment.product = product
            new_comment.save()
            return redirect('product_detail', product_id=product_id)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'store/item_details.html', {'product': product, 'comments': comments, 'form': form})

urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('product/<int:product_id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]

models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from store.models import Item


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

forms.py:
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']

item_details.html:
<h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
        <p style="margin: 0em 0 1em 0em">
          Товар належить категорії {% for tag in item.tags.all %}
          <b><a href="{% url 'store:tag_details' tag.slug %}">{{ tag }}</a></b>
          {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %} {% endfor %}
        </p>
        {% if item.image %}
        <p>
          <span class="image left"><img src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 350px" />
            {% else %}
            <p>
              <span class="image left"><img src="{% static 'images/pic14.jpg' %}?v=1.0" alt />
                {% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'cart:add_to_cart' item.slug %}" class="button small" style="margin-top: 10px">
                  Додати у корзину</a>
              </span>
              {{ item.description }}{{ item.description }}
            </p>
            {% if item.old_price %}
            <p>
              Стара ціна: <s>{{ item.old_price }} гривень</s> Нова ціна:
              <b>{{ item.price }}</b> гривень
            </p>
            {% else %}
            <p>Ціна: <b>{{ item.price }}</b> гривень</p>
            {% endif %}
        </p>
        <h2>Comments:</h2>
      <ul>
        {% for comment in comments %}
            <li>{{ comment.text }} - {{ comment.user.username }} ({{ comment.created_at }})</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No comments yet.</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>

      <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
      <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

Буду благодарен, если поможете найти ошибку!
